# Linear Algebra take on Chi-Squared

Tags: self-study, linear-algebra, chi-squared-distribution

If I have a system where my output is the sum of my input and white Gaussian noise:
$Y=x+w$  and   $w$~$N(0,\sigma^2I)$

now, I want to determine the distribution for $||y/\sigma||^2 = y^Ty/\sigma^2$

I'm fairly certain (not positive) that this distribution is a chi-squared distribution because $y^Ty = \sum_1^ny_i^2$ which is a sum of squared normal R.V.s

I'm just not entirely sure on how to prove this!

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: 1. Check the RHS of $||y/\sigma||^2 = y^Ty/\sigma$ carefully.  2. having a "sum of squared normal RVs" is not sufficient for a chi-square. (You may be able to argue for a *noncentral* chi-square by invoking the fact of their independence though.)

Answer (score 1):

In general this should actually follow a non-central $\chi^2$ distribution, since your normal random variables are not centered at 0, if x $\neq 0$